# Could not load file or assembly 'accoremgd,Version=20.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' one of its dependencies

Tags: vb.net, autocad

I am beginner to AutoCAD customization in VB.net.
I have added following references to my project.
1. accoremgd.dll
2. AcCui.dll
3. acmgd.dll
4. acdbmgd.dll

following is my code:

```
     Imports Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices
     Imports Autodesk.AutoCAD.DatabaseServices
     Imports Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime
     Imports System.IO
     Imports Autodesk.AutoCAD.Interop
     Imports Autodesk.AutoCAD.Interop.Common
     Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

    Public Class Form1

    Private Sub btnShow_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnShow.Click
    Dim str_path As String
    str_path = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Name
    txtbox1.Text = str_path
End Sub
End Class
```

And I am getting following exception:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'accoremgd, Version=20.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

What to do?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: is this a .DLL that you NETLOAD or a .exe (Windows Application)?

Comment: Its Windows Application.

Comment: in that case you CANNOT use accoremgd reference...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to use Ac****Mgd.dll references from a .EXE project (Windows Application), then it will not work. [See this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38480420/4838205).

Answer (score 0):

In most of the cases I encountered this error it was one of *... its dependencies...*.

In this case you can add a handler to catch the AssemblyResolve event:

```
AddHandler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve, AddressOf AppDomain_AssemblyResolve

    Private Shared Function AppDomain_AssemblyResolve(sender As Object, e As ResolveEventArgs) As Reflection.Assembly
        Debug.WriteLine(e.Name)
        Return Nothing
    End Function
```

Then have a look at the output and see if there are assemblies missing.